# Convert the BSTR hexa decimal string to BYTE * in C++

Tags: c++, hex, converters

I was trying to convert the BSTR string to Hex BYTE *

I receive the response from the COM as BSTR

My RAW methods in tlh

```
 virtual HRESULT __stdcall test(
        /*[in]*/ BSTR domain,
        /*[in]*/ BSTR snap,
        /*[out,retval]*/ BSTR * pRetVal ) = 0;
```

> BSTR aa = L"559EB7F000260044F06BB01A3A000055";

Which i want to convert into BYTE myHex[16]

> Sample response
>   {0x55,0x97,0xD6,0x00,0x02,0x60,0x01,0x44,0xF0,0x6B,0xB0,0x1A,0x3A,0x00,0x00,0x55};

Comment: When you "tried to covert", what went wrong?

Comment: couldn't able to identify the issue, am implementing this for VSS hardware provider, if i hardcode the value for BYTE * , its working and the VSS can able to detect my disk, if i convert the string to hex, it couldnt able to understand my disk

Comment: How did you try to *parse* the input string and what was the output? What did you try?

Comment: am using same kind of code which Matt McNabb suggested, in VSS am getting error Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFF56B089E4 (VssHardwareProvider.dll) in dllhost.exe: Stack cookie instrumentation code detected a stack-based buffer overrun... while debuging its not throwing any error on the conversion code but if i commented the code, its working fine ( but my problem isnt solved )

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use `swscanf`. You could do it via a stringstream also.

```
#include <cstdio>
```

...

```
for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
{
    if ( 1 != std::swscanf(aa + 2 * i, L"%02X", myHex + i) )
         throw std::runtime_error("Conversion failure");
}
```